# Selecting data from json in React & axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using axios in React.

If I want to get the value of image URL I would use:

```
<img src={data.results[0].picture.medium} alt="random user" />
```

[image: If I want]

How can I get the value "id" the from below json API response ?

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios("https://www.blibli.com/backend/search/products?category=T--1000001")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return "Error!";

  return (
    <>
      <p>{data.products[0].id}</p>
      {/* <img src={data.results[0].picture.medium} alt="random user" /> */}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: do you only need the first ID. it shows an array of 40 products. if u want first `data.data.produts[0].id`

Comment: it returned "Error!"

Comment: currently what get display? I would expect you get an error if you just do like that `{data?.product[0].id}`. Try do this instead `{data && data?.products[0].id}`